Light theme in 24.04?
I just upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.  Budgie desktop.
Now when I open applications like Filezilla and G-edit, they open in a "dark theme", which is tough for me to read (I'm not young).
How do I go to a "light" theme?  The "Budgie Makeovers and Layouts" tool is confusing.
